# Why must a block in NAND SSDs be erased before it can be reprogammed?

Tags: computer-architecture, hardware, nand-flash, ssd, wear-leveling

Before programming a NAND based SSD in page-level we have to always erase by block-level which increases write amplification. why is it so and how do we mitigate it?
what is the necessity of erasing before writing?

Comment: Writing can only change a bit in one direction. Erasing is the only one way to change bits in the other direction. Having an entire block erased at once allows the device to be simpler and fit greater capacity in the same size die. [All explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Block_erasure)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. There's plenty of text already written on this subject on the internet. This site is for specific and well-detailed questions on electronic design.

Comment: It is built out of flash.  That is how flash works, writes flip bits only one direction, erase is how you flip them the other and you can only erase in blocks (pages).

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304993/why-can-nand-flash-memory-cells-only-be-directly-written-to-when-they-are-empty): "Why must a block in NAND SSDs be erased before it can be reprogammed?"

Answer (score 2):

Usually because the act of writing does not empty the unwritten-to blocks.

So if the first program used blocks 1 to 150 and the new version only uses blocks 1 to 132, then the old information will still exist in blocks 133 to 150 possibly causing errors.